# How to modify the Request of a POST Message in Java?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm at the beginning of creating a Webservice with Java.
I want to POST a XML-Request to a Restful Webservice and the Response should be a modified XML. So actually just the Root-Element of the Request should be changed and it should be added another element.

Request:

```
<Request>
    <name>name</name>
</Request>
```

Response:

```
 <Response>
    <name>name</name>
    <status>created</status>
</Response>
```

Currently I'm only returning the Request.
Which is the best/easiest way to modify the Request? Can I do it with JAXB?

```
public class Resource {
    @POST
    @Produces
    @Consumes
    public Request request(Request r) {
        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Jersey to expose the rest api. As RedFive mentioned there are plenty of examples available to build rest api using jersey(jax-rs implementation) on internet. I did a small POC while learning jersey. You can find a sample POST API implementation [here](https://github.com/sumveds/rest-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/faraox/rest/poc/resource/PersonResource.java#L48). I am passing request bean(as Person class object). The request json/xml is unmarshalled to Person object. Instead of returning object of **Request** type, you have to return **Response** object. Hope this example helps you in learning jersey.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response makeRequest(Request req) {
    Response res = new Response();
    res.setName(req.getName());
    return Response.entity(res).status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
}
```

One thing I want to point out that you may not return the status in the response body. You return 201(CREATED) http status code which resembles the same thing.